# Button stays 'pressed down' in Bootstrap theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I am in the process of setting up the theme for my website using Jekyll.

I am using the Bootstrap example theme for this and I am currently facing an issue where by the Home button stays 'pressed down' when on another page such as the About page.

Here is a link to the CSS file: https://github.com/Dansmithyy/dansmeuktheme/blob/master/css/main.scss

Is there any way of changing this so that the buttons stay pressed down when the user is on that specific page?

Answer (score 0):

Your main menu is hard coded in html. And it remains the same all over your pages.

```
<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

My code inspector tell me that a rule is applied to

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a
```

Here is the origin of the symptom.

The real cause of your problem is that your are hard coding your main menu.

If you look in your original `default.html` file and then in `_includes/header.html` you can see things like `{% include header.html %}` and `{% for page in site.pages %}...`

The last tag help you automatically generate a menu. I've added the active class trick in it to save you some time :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
{% for node in site.pages %}
  {% if node.title %}
  <li class="{% if page.url == node.url %} active{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ node.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ node.title }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**NOTE** the `{% if node.title %}` if you want a page to appear in the menu you must put a `title` variable in the page's front matter. eg: `title: My nice title`

Comment: Just add this in the default html file or do I need to remove anything?

Comment: Thanks for your help David, here is my code now - pastebin.com/dUDsGNHR - Currently my home button is now missing as I have removed that list, is there anyway to have the home button back but still have the same styling i.e not staying "pressed down"?